# Programmatically Listing `C-sources` in Haskell Cabal Files

Tags: haskell, cabal, ffi

I am involved in a Haskell project which involves a lot of C FFI. Thus, for every `src/HaskellFile.hs` I have in my project, I have a corresponding `src/HaskellFile.c` C source file. This means I have to manually this all of these C sources in my cabal project:

```
C-sources:           src/HaskellFile1.c, src/HaskellFile2.c
```

...and so forth.

**Question:** Is it possible to programmatically list out these files in my cabal project file? Something like:

```
C-sources:           src/*.c
```

..? (For the record, I tried the above and it didn't work).

Comment: Huh, that's pretty lame. Other fields support wildcards (ctrl-f "wildcard" here: https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html)

Comment: Indeed, this is likely a bug! Though you can also populate this field programmatically using Setup.hs, as described below. I have done this when working on autogenerated packages, as the wildcard functionality in Cabal is rather restricted.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to add a comment, but stackoverflow tells me that I need *50 reputation* to comment!

You should be able to do this with a custom `Setup.hs` file.
Here is an example that might help you:
https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-noprelude-4.7.0.0/src/Setup.hs

Comment: It's unclear to me from that link how to add `src/*.c` and `include/*.h`. I added a new question for it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41575528/how-to-automatically-include-haskell-c-sources-through-setup-hs-build-script).

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, no programming is allowed in cabal files. This level of simplicity has some drawbacks, as you note, but it also has some benefits: tools are more predictable, and it is drop-dead simple to read somebody else's cabal file (you don't have to turn on your programmer brain!).