# How to automatically include Haskell C-sources through `Setup.hs` build script?

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

In a Haskell project's cabal file we have the following sections:

```
C-Sources:    src/A.c
            , src/B.c
            , ...

Includes:     include/A.h
            , include/B.h
            , ...
```

Unfortunately, wildcarding in these sections is not allowed (as confirmed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41292462/programmatically-listing-c-sources-in-haskell-cabal-files)):

```
-- this doesn't work:
C-Sources: src/*.c
Includes:  include/*.h
```

**Question:** How can one alter `Setup.hs` to automatically include `src/*.c` and `include/*.h` as above?

Comment: The `preConf` hook is probably what you need to modify - this has an output type of `IO HookedBuildInfo`, and `HookedBuildInfo` contains a `cSources :: [FilePath]` field and a `includeDirs :: [FilePath]` field - presumably you can write the Haskell function to find your files, and then it is just a matter of calling the default hook and then appending (or prepending? might make a difference to the linker...) to the respective lists.

Comment: It seems possible that [hpack](https://github.com/sol/hpack#readme) supports file globbing for `C-Sources`.

Comment: @sjakobi: I just tried hpack and it does not not (I filed a GitHub issue about it though).